# static assertion on noexcept for protected constructors

Tags: c++, noexcept, declval

I'm attempting to assert following protected class constructors may or may not throw as follows:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

class X
{
protected:
    X() noexcept(false) { }
    X(int) noexcept { }
};

int main()
{
    // should fail
    static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<X>().X()));

    // should pass
    static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<X>().X(3)));

    // will fail regardless of noexcept because constructor is protected,
    // but should pass if default ctor is noexcept and public
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<X>);

    return 0;
}
```

static assertion should fail in first case and pass in second.

error is `type name is not allowed` and I'm not sure what syntax I should use or what would be better approach.

In third `static_assert` case it will always fail because constructor is not public.

Comment: You're not allowed to call constructors.  Use a trait for this instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

Comment: It will not work for protected constructors, I'll update my post anyway.

Comment: Inherit a dummy class from `X`, then apply the trait to it. Alternatively, change `X` to have protected destructor and public constructors.

Comment: I can't change access level, but inheriting for the purpose of assertion should work. I though there may be more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: What's the point of testing a constructor from a location where you don't have access to it?

Comment: @Phil1970 static analysis of hierarchy of classes, to quickly detect which classes poison derived classes. I use this in separate test compilation unit.